# ReactJS and Material UI - Interconnected Lists

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js

I am in the process of learning ReactJS (NextJS) with Material UI. Currently i am trying to figure out, the best way to implement "interconnected lists". My idea is, to represent a hierarchy with n levels in n different lists side by side.

What would be the best approach for something like this? All i can think of is a huge mess off callbacks all over the place in one main file which coordinates everything, with one callback to the 1st list rendering the second list and the 2nd list rendering the 3rd list etc.

Note that i am new to JavaScript and to WebDev in general. I would only like to know, if that's the way to go or if there is an easier, simpler way.

Comment: See [`TreeView`](https://material-ui.com/components/tree-view/)

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! I will look into it.